# Formatting JSON for highchart

Tags: javascript, java, json, highcharts

I have a `servlet` running that's pulling  data from a `DB` on a doGet and responding with a `JSON` formatted string to populate a `Highchart.js` time-series chart:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String json = "";
        String sDate = request.getParameter("start");
        String eDate = request.getParameter("end");
        String app = request.getParameter("app");
        String env = request.getParameter("env");


            if (sDate != null && eDate != null) {
                Timestamp from = TimestampUtils.parseTimestamp(sDate, null);
                Timestamp to = TimestampUtils.parseTimestamp(eDate, null);

                try {
                    throughPutList = interop.getThroughputEntriesInTimespan(env, app, from, to);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int counter = 1;
                if (throughPutList != null) {
                    json += "[";
                }
                assert throughPutList != null;
                for (ThroughputEntry chartModel : throughPutList) {

                    json += "[" + (chartModel.getRetrieved().getEpochSecond()* TimestampUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND + "," + chartModel.getThroughput() +  "]");

                    if (counter < throughPutList.size()) {
                        json += ",";
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                if (throughPutList != null) {
                    json += "]";
                }
                if (throughPutList == null) {
                    json = "No record found";
                }
            } else {
                json = "Date must be selected." + "App : " + app + " " + eDate;

            }
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
}
```

I'm new to `javascript`, `highchart` and `JSON`, is it possible to refine this to maybe use actual `JSON` objects / arrays rather than a string, or is the method I have a reasonable way to work this.

Comment: Maybe you can use a library that can convert the java input to json, (Ex : Gson or jackson).
Many advdantages if you use this methode : 100% using of java object, no matter if you forget a " or if you forget on key.
I try to give you a small code in few minutes

Comment: I was thinking of useing one the mentioned libraries to parse it into `JSON`, but can I use those libraries to parse it into a `JSON` format that `highchart.js` understands

Comment: I just verified the format of json String required by highcharts, i agree with you, there is no need to use those librairies because there is no need to have keys and values.
So i suggest to keep your code but with some clean to do.
Use StringBuilder ton concat values it will be more performant when your list will be more bigger.
Try also to initialise variables with request :
Ex : String app = request.getParameter("app") ? request.getParameter("app") : "value";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You construct a JSON string by hand which runs the risk of having syntax errors in the result string. Since you are just producing arrays of arrays of numbers this risk seems to be controllable . Else you would want to use something like a `JSONWriter` provided by all of the common JSON libraries.

A small performance improvement would be to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` for variable `json`.

I would improve the error handling. You are returning an error message in case no data is found or parameters are missing.

In the first case I would just return the empty array and let the client figure out that the data is empty.

If required parameters are missing I would answer with a HTTP error 400 (Bad request):

```
response.sendError(400);
```

If a runtime error occurs when retrieving the data I would not swallow the exception but send an internal server error (500) and log the exception.